# json in Oracle 10 g

Tags: json, oracle, plsql

I have Oracle 10 g.
This is json's string: `[{ "id": "1.00", "contactBy": "Rajesh Kumar"}, { "id": "2.00", "contactBy": "Rakesh Kumar"}]`.
Can I get the two column and row at the same time?

```
select regexp_replace(regexp_substr('[{"id": "1.00", "contactBy":"Rajesh Kumar"}
                                  ,{"id": "2","contactBy": "Emmanuel Test"}]'
                                  , '"contactBy":\s*("(\w| )")', 1, level)
                                  , '"contactBy":\s"((\w| ))"', '\1', 1, 1) contact 
from dual 
connect by regexp_substr('[{"id": "1","contactBy":"Rajesh Kumar"}
                       ,{"id": "2","contactBy": "Emmanuel Test"}]'
                       , '"contactBy":\s("(\w| )*")', 1, level) is not null
```

Comment: 1) What *"decimal character number (112,000)"*? 2) You're selecting from `DUAL`, so what *"two or more of any column and row"* are you referring to? `DUAL` has exactly one row with one column.

Comment: Upon request I would like to get into that

Comment: Your comment is making even less sense that the question. Get into *what*? And you didn't even answer my first question: What *"decimal character number"*?

Comment: Upon request I would like to get into that                                                    id        contactBy                                                                                           1.00    Rajesh Kumar
2    Emmanuel Test

Comment: Please execute sql request and You will see

Comment: Sorry, I give up. I still have **no idea** what it is you're trying to do. And no, I will not *"execute sql request"* and see. If you want us to *see*, then insert output in question text. Please read "[How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)"

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Please post your desired output. Or don't, the choice is entirely yours. But we cannot help you if you don't explain yourself clearly.

Comment: You will probably have more luck by installing PL/JSON: https://github.com/pljson/pljson

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the answer:

```
select regexp_replace(regexp_substr('[{"id": "1.00", "contactBy":"Rajesh Kumar"},{"id": "2","contactBy": "Emmanuel Test+-"}]',
                                     '"contactBy":\s*(".*?")', 1, level),
                      '"contactBy":\s*"(.*?)"', '\1', 1, 1) contact, 
       regexp_replace(regexp_substr('[{"id": "1.00", "contactBy":"Rajesh Kumar"},{"id": "2","contactBy": "Emmanuel Test+-"}]',
                                     '"id":\s*(".*?")', 1, level),
                      '"id":\s*"(.*?)"', '\1', 1, 1) contact               
 from dual
 connect by regexp_substr('[{"id": "1","contactBy":"Rajesh Kumar"},{"id": "2","contactBy": "Emmanuel Test+-"}]', '"contactBy":\s*(".*?")', 1, level) is not null;
```